# How can I insert a php code into a shortcode in HTML?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I would like to add a php code into a shortcode code in HTML editor.
My shortcode looks like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[eapi keyword="KEYWORD" n=25]'); ?>
```

It works, if I put just a word instead of KEYWORD. Now I would like to add an individual title with this php code:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

So I inserted it into the shortcode like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[eapi keyword="<?php the_title(); ?>
" n=25]'); ?>
```

But unfortunately it did not work. How can I successfully insert this php code into the shortcode?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are starting with a single quote which makes the contents literal and prevents you from using variables. You may want to use double quotes and then a backslash before any of the quotes inside.

Comment: you already started php open tag and close tag, issue is you again started php open tag <?php echo do_shortcode('[eapi keyword="<?php the_title(); ?>
" n=25]'); ?> try this <?php echo do_shortcode('[eapi keyword=".$title."]' ) ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution but I am not familiar with the plugin/context you are using this in. But maybe this will give you some ideas:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[eapi keyword=\"" . the_title() . "\" n=25]"); ?>
```

So I removed the inner php tags for one. I switched the outer quotes to double quotes since you can't use functions/variables within single quotes. At the same time I concatenated the title function since I don't think it can be interpreted within the quotes. That also might negate the need for double quotes, but force of habit.

EDIT - Some other use examples outside of the original question for clarity.

Variable in the string requires double quotes:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[eapi keyword='{$variable}' n=25]"); ?>
```

Variable concatenated can use single or double quotes:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[eapi keyword='" . {$variable} . "' n=25]"); ?>
```

Keywords and functions must be concatenated:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[".KEYWORD." keyword='".func()."' n=25 x={$var}]"); ?>
```

Comment: If i want to add a shortcode of a similar plugin, which looks like this: <?php echo do_shortcode('[amazon bestseller="KEYWORD" items="10"]'); ?>
How can i implement it like you did it above? I tried this: <?php echo do_shortcode('[amazon bestseller=\"" . the_title() . "\" items="10"]'); ?> . but it did not work :/

Comment: For the above code you are  having opening quote as single and closing as double

Comment: `<?php echo do_shortcode("[amazon bestseller=\'" . the_title() . "\' items='10']"); ?>` [Jang Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47934947/7678788) is perfect

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for the reply. Unfortunately the code : <?php echo do_shortcode("[amazon bestseller=\'" . the_title() . "\' items='10']"); ?> did not work. I am overasked, what else i can add to make this work. I tried to replace the ". the title()" into ". get_the_title()" but it did not work as well

Comment: I don't think I am understanding correctly. Are you putting a period after get_the_title() and before the next double quote?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
 <?php do_shortcode('[eapi keyword="' . get_the_title() . '"]'; ?>
```

You'll want get_the_title because it will return the title instead of directly outputting it (as the_title will). As you are already in PHP mode, you don't need any additional

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to modify your eapi plug in to support your requirement.

For example, you can make a rule on your eapi plug to analysis the parameter's keyword.

1) if it is a simple string, return directly

2) if it is a string as similar as "**{{{......}}}**", use eval function to run it as a php script and then return.